# Optaplanner - The benchmarkConfigResource does not exist as a classpath resource in the classLoader

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, optaplanner, drools-planner

I'm new to **OptaPlanner** and I'm focusing on **benchmarking**.
I started playing around with the benchmark in **Eclipse**.
I followed the documentation (http://docs.jboss.org/optaplanner/release/6.4.0.Final/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#buildAndRunAPlannerBenchmark), but when trying to run, I got this **error**:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The benchmarkConfigResource (prova/src/prova/nurseRosteringBenchmarkConfig.xml) does not exist as a classpath resource in the classLoader (sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@73d16e93).
    at org.optaplanner.benchmark.impl.XStreamXmlPlannerBenchmarkFactory.configure(XStreamXmlPlannerBenchmarkFactory.java:100)
    at org.optaplanner.benchmark.api.PlannerBenchmarkFactory.createFromXmlResource(PlannerBenchmarkFactory.java:45)
    at prova.ClasseJava.main(ClasseJava.java:10)
```

Maybe I'm doing something wrong in Java (I need to review it), so here is my **code**:

```
package prova;

import org.optaplanner.benchmark.api.PlannerBenchmark;
import org.optaplanner.benchmark.api.PlannerBenchmarkFactory;

public class ClasseJava {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Ok - Before");
        PlannerBenchmarkFactory plannerBenchmarkFactory = PlannerBenchmarkFactory.createFromXmlResource(
                "prova/src/prova/nurseRosteringBenchmarkConfig.xml");
        System.out.println("Ok - After");
        PlannerBenchmark plannerBenchmark = plannerBenchmarkFactory.buildPlannerBenchmark();
        plannerBenchmark.benchmark();
    }   
}
```

**Info**: I've placed the file nurseRosteringBenchmarkConfig.xml in the same *ClasseJava*'s package (*prova*).

Thank you for a little help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classpath resources are like package names and full classnames.
Since your packagename is "prova", your classpath resource is "prova/nurseRosteringBenchmarkConfig.xml".

```
    PlannerBenchmarkFactory plannerBenchmarkFactory = PlannerBenchmarkFactory.createFromXmlResource(
            "prova/nurseRosteringBenchmarkConfig.xml");
```